# Issue drawing custom UIView with CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, core-graphics

I am trying to make a custom vertical switch with CoreGraphics. I have switch background and the switch thumb drawing in separate views, but for some reason, I can't seem to set the background color of the thumb view to clearcolor. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

```
![import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ThumbView:UIView {

    var thumbPath = UIBezierPath()
    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
       // self.opaque = false
      //  self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.opaque = false
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let contentFrame = rect
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        let bgPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.frame)
        let bgColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        bgColor.setFill()
        bgPath.fill()

        self.backgroundColor = bgColor;

        let white = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)
        let shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.1, 3.1)
        let shadowBlurRadius: CGFloat = 5
        let shadow = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        //// thumb Drawing
        thumbPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.height, rect.size.width))
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius, shadow.CGColor)
        white.setFill()
        thumbPath.fill()
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }
}

class VerticalSwitch: UIView {

    var switchBackgroundPath = UIBezierPath()
    var thumbView = ThumbView()

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        thumbView = ThumbView()
        NSLog("%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame))
        self.addSubview(thumbView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        thumbView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, self.frame.size.width - 10, self.frame.size.width - 10)
    }

    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        let contentFrame = rect
        //// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        //// Color Declarations
        let gDGreen = UIColor(red: 0.157, green: 0.475, blue: 0.153, alpha: 1.000)

        //// Shadow Declarations
        let innerShadow = UIColor.darkGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9)
        let innerShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.1, -5.1)
        let innerShadowBlurRadius: CGFloat = 10

        //// switchBackground Drawing
        switchBackgroundPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 85.36, contentFrame.minY + 0.06764 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 100, contentFrame.minY + 0.23095 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 95.12, contentFrame.minY + 0.11274 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 100, contentFrame.minY + 0.17184 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 100, contentFrame.minY + 0.76905 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 85.36, contentFrame.minY + 0.93236 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 100, contentFrame.minY + 0.82816 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 95.12, contentFrame.minY + 0.88726 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 14.64, contentFrame.minY + 0.93236 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 65.83, contentFrame.minY + 1.02255 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 34.17, contentFrame.minY + 1.02255 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX, contentFrame.minY + 0.76905 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 4.88, contentFrame.minY + 0.88726 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX, contentFrame.minY + 0.82816 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX, contentFrame.minY + 0.23095 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 14.64, contentFrame.minY + 0.06764 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX, contentFrame.minY + 0.17184 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 4.88, contentFrame.minY + 0.11274 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 85.36, contentFrame.minY + 0.06764 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 34.17, contentFrame.minY + -0.02255 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 65.83, contentFrame.minY + -0.02255 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.closePath()
        gDGreen.setFill()
        switchBackgroundPath.fill()

        ////// switchBackground Inner Shadow
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextClipToRect(context, switchBackgroundPath.bounds)
        CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 0)
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, CGColorGetAlpha(innerShadow.CGColor))
        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, nil)
        let switchBackgroundOpaqueShadow = innerShadow.colorWithAlphaComponent(1)
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, innerShadowOffset, innerShadowBlurRadius, switchBackgroundOpaqueShadow.CGColor)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceOut)
        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, nil)

        switchBackgroundOpaqueShadow.setFill()
        switchBackgroundPath.fill()

        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context)
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    }
}]
```

Comment: Try to add `CGContextClearRect(context, rect)` just after you got current context.

Comment: @Keenle Doesn't work, still having the same issue.

Comment: In `init` method try to set `self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor`

Comment: @Keenle Nope, same issue.

Comment: Also I have tried setting self.opaque to false in the ThumbView but then the entire view disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create thumbView using constructor with frame parameter:

```
thumbView = ThumbView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 0, 0))
```

And ThumbView `init(frame: CGRect)` should be:

```
init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.opaque = false
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Alternatively you can create parameterless construct in ThumbView but must call `super.init(frame:CGRectMake(0,0, 0, 0))` and set opaque and background properties anyway.

**UPDATE:**

- You also forgot to call `CGContextRestoreGState` in ThumbView `drawRect:` method. Should be added in the end of the method.
- And do forgot to call `CGContextEndTransparencyLayer` in VerticalSwitch `drawRect:` method. Should be added right after another `CGContextEndTransparencyLayer` method invocation.

Emulator screenshot:

[image: Final Screenshot]

**All code (with fixes):**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ThumbView:UIView {

    var thumbPath = UIBezierPath()
    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
         self.opaque = false
          self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.opaque = false
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let contentFrame = rect
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        let bgPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.frame)
        let bgColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        bgColor.setFill()
        bgPath.fill()

        self.backgroundColor = bgColor;

        let white = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)
        let shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.1, 3.1)
        let shadowBlurRadius: CGFloat = 5
        let shadow = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        //// thumb Drawing
        thumbPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.height, rect.size.width))
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius, shadow.CGColor)
        white.setFill()
        thumbPath.fill()
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }
}

class VerticalSwitch: UIView {

    var switchBackgroundPath = UIBezierPath()
    var thumbView = ThumbView()

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        thumbView = ThumbView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 0, 0))
        NSLog("%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame))
        self.addSubview(thumbView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        thumbView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, self.frame.size.width - 10, self.frame.size.width - 10)
    }

    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        let contentFrame = rect
        //// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        //// Color Declarations
        let gDGreen = UIColor(red: 0.157, green: 0.475, blue: 0.153, alpha: 1.000)

        //// Shadow Declarations
        let innerShadow = UIColor.darkGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9)
        let innerShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.1, -5.1)
        let innerShadowBlurRadius: CGFloat = 10

        //// switchBackground Drawing
        switchBackgroundPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 85.36, contentFrame.minY + 0.06764 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 100, contentFrame.minY + 0.23095 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 95.12, contentFrame.minY + 0.11274 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 100, contentFrame.minY + 0.17184 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 100, contentFrame.minY + 0.76905 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 85.36, contentFrame.minY + 0.93236 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 100, contentFrame.minY + 0.82816 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 95.12, contentFrame.minY + 0.88726 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 14.64, contentFrame.minY + 0.93236 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 65.83, contentFrame.minY + 1.02255 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 34.17, contentFrame.minY + 1.02255 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX, contentFrame.minY + 0.76905 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 4.88, contentFrame.minY + 0.88726 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX, contentFrame.minY + 0.82816 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX, contentFrame.minY + 0.23095 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 14.64, contentFrame.minY + 0.06764 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX, contentFrame.minY + 0.17184 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 4.88, contentFrame.minY + 0.11274 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 85.36, contentFrame.minY + 0.06764 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 34.17, contentFrame.minY + -0.02255 * contentFrame.height), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(contentFrame.minX + 65.83, contentFrame.minY + -0.02255 * contentFrame.height))
        switchBackgroundPath.closePath()
        gDGreen.setFill()
        switchBackgroundPath.fill()

        ////// switchBackground Inner Shadow
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextClipToRect(context, switchBackgroundPath.bounds)
        CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 0)
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, CGColorGetAlpha(innerShadow.CGColor))
        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, nil)
        let switchBackgroundOpaqueShadow = innerShadow.colorWithAlphaComponent(1)
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, innerShadowOffset, innerShadowBlurRadius, switchBackgroundOpaqueShadow.CGColor)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceOut)
        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, nil)

        switchBackgroundOpaqueShadow.setFill()
        switchBackgroundPath.fill()

        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context)
        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context)
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but the ThumbView is not showing at all still. Did this actually work for you?

Comment: How do you init VerticalSwitch? Can you share the code?

Comment: Just using a storyboard. So the init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) is being called. Let me try it in code instead.

Comment: I use xCode 6 beta 3. The view was just dropped into root view and I specified you class in attribute inspector.

Comment: Try to clean project and rebuild. Aw well try to reset emulator.

Comment: So now try to get the white borders around the switch to clearColor instead of white. I have the thumb showing now.

Comment: I've updated the answer. BTW, last fix revealed the inner shadow.

Comment: @Keenie Could you do me a favor and post the entire code in your answer as I still am having issues. I appreciate all the help :)

Comment: Posted. You also need to go to the storyboard and set view's background to clear color.